# Fragment Back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, back-button

I know how to add a Fragment to the backstack but how do I know, when the user presses the back Button, which fragment I left and which I went to? I need to do a certain action depending on this so I need to know from and to which fragment I am going. Specifically I need to know which fragment I left so if it is a certain fragment, I can remove a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onBackPressed` in `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
      FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
      Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame); // get the fragment that is currently loaded in placeholder
      Object tag = f.getTag();
      // do handling with help of tag here
      // call super method
      super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: ty, this helps. but what I do not understand is that I end up in that function also when I add to the stack, i.e. when I am not pressing the back button, why is that and how do I avoid it?

Comment: That sounds werid to me, I don't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Fragment like this :

```
ArticleMain articalemain = new ArticleMain();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_Top, articalemain,     "MY_FRAGMENT").commit();
```

While Removing the Fragments do like this :

```
ArticleMain myFragment = (ArticleMain) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT");
                if (myFragment.isVisible()) {
                    // add your code here
                    myFragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .remove(myFragment).commit();
                }
```